# How can I find an element in a pre-sorted array without iterating all of it?

Tags: c#, voronoi

I am trying to find the highest value of an intersection of a line with an array of  parabolas ( I am implementing a fortune line and this is a site event ).

I noticed the values tend to grow bigger as I get closer to the biggest value ( the one I am looking for ) and then get smaller again, as if they had been sorted. An exemple would be this :
`[f(a) = -3, f(b) = -1, f(c) = 4, f(d) = 18, f(e) = 67, f(f) = 34, f(g) = 8, f(h) = -7]`
( with 67 being the value I need to get ).

Since calculating the intersections is not as fast as just reading a value of an array, I was wondering if there was a faster way to get the biggest value without iterating on all of the parabolas.

Since the voronoï diagramm is big, the array of parabolas is expected to be ranging from 10k to 20k elements on average. The biggest value can be anywhere in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence that is increasing and then decreasing or decreasing and then increasing is called bitonic sequence. You can find the maximum/minimum point in O(log n), here is [a link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-element-bitonic-array/) to an example implementation. In fact once you find this point, you can find any element in O(log n) by using binary search.